# window.open() cannot open the window more than once in CHROME after upgraded from 33 to 35

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, window.open

Here is the code:

```
<modal:button type="print" onClick="
    if($('printMenu').selectedIndex == 0) { 
       printLarge('${printForm}', 'large')
    } 
    if($('printMenu').selectedIndex == 1){
       printSmall('${printForm}', 'small')
    }
    if($('printMenu').selectedIndex == 2){                                                     
       printEmail('${printForm}', 'email')
    };

    printWindow=window.open('../print/openLargeWindow.html','printWindow','width=1000,height=800');" defaultBehavior="true"/>
```

the functionality is select a option from the drop down menu, click the button then a window pop up with the content will be printed.

it works perfectly in IE and FF. And it works perfectly also in Chrome 33(before I upgrade it). Since I upgrade chrome to 35, the popup window only popup once---after you close the popup window, and click the button again, then nothing happens.

I tried to use different url to open it, not work.
I check the popup window blocker in chrome, it is disable.

Each time before click the second time, the open one is already closed by me.(no duplicated one open, but still not let you open the 2nd one)

After I changed it to "_blank" instead of "printWindow" it lets you open the 2nd one, even 3rd one, but after a few tries. it stops working again.

Is there anyone that has the experience or suggestion to work around or solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is this `<modal:button`? That's no HTML I've ever seen. Also, it's "it works perfectly", not "it works perfect".

Comment: Sometime even after closing the Firefox window, the process is still running in the background. Just have a look at the task manager and find the processes running for Firefox. Try it again after sometime because after some time the process will be closed automatically. Have a look at [MDN - Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) for valid syntax. Even you can try with [Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a different window name. If the window `printWindow` already exists the browser will use the open one instead of opening another one. Specify `_blank` to always open a new window.

(I wonder why that worked in IE and FF at all. It should not with your current code).

Comment: If do not close the open one, sure, 2nd one never get open, But my case is that each time before click the second time, the open one is already closed by me. Also after I changed it to "_blank" it lets you open the 2nd one, even 3rd one, but after a few tries. it stops working again.

Comment: even `window.open(url, '_blank')`, sometimes still cannot open a new tab in chrome